# C# WPF datagrid row height won't exceed datagrid height

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

In C# and WPF and Visual Studio I am displaying some data from a sql database in a datagrid, in the description column it might have many many lines, and currently it will truncate display of a line rather than add a scroll.  when there are multiple lines it will still truncate each line at max of parent datagrid height .
[problem shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVHSU.png)

below is what I've tried so far(this is why the screenshot has 2 description columns shown).  adding scrollviewer to the datatemplate makes a greyed out scrollbar show, but nothing else.

```
          <DataGrid  VerticalAlignment="Top"  MaxHeight="225" Height="225" SelectionUnit="FullRow" MouseDoubleClick="Loaditem" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="grid" Margin="7,510,33,0"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" Width="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                                <TextBlock 
                                  Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Height="10000"
                                    MinHeight="10000"
                                    MaxHeight="10000"
                                     />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                
                
                <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CopyCommand" />
                    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>

                    <!-- This is required to handle CTRL + C when something is selected in the DataGrid -->
                    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Command="Copy" />
                    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid>
```

Where I add the other columns in code behind currently

```
         grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "QTY", Width = new DataGridLength(0.025, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Qty") });

            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Description", Width = new DataGridLength(0.49, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Description") });
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Part Number", Width = new DataGridLength(0.1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("PartNo")  });
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Cost", Width = new DataGridLength(0.085, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star), Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Cost") { StringFormat = "$0.00" } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue is that you are setting the `Height` of the `TextBlock`, and not the `ScrollViewer`. So, in your case, the `ScrollViewer` is growing with the content, and therefore there is nothing to scoll.

If you move your `Height` and/or `MaxHeight` poreties to the `ScrollViewer`, you should be able to achieve the scrolling affect you are looking for:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  MaxHeight="100">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

Resulting scrollable cell:
[image: Resulting scrollable cell]

Comment: This makes so much sense, Thank you!